# PhoneGap mobile irc client app using native tcp sockets, websockets?

Tags: sockets, cordova, websocket, symbian, irc

Hi I would like to know if it possible to realize an iOS/Android irc client app using PhoneGap.

I think I am going to need to use native tcp sockets: does anybody know if PhoneGap allow me to make use of them? I checked the api doc but for some reason couldn't find the part dealing with it?

Also, if PhoneGap supports websockets, is it a feasible option to use that for this kind of app?

I'd like to have some kind of basic advice on wheter or not I am on a good path.

I'm also thinking of using Rhomobile, (for which I have the same doubts I said above, though I did not investigate enough) but for now I would like to go with PhoneGap because it also says to support Symbian devices, while Rhomobile discontinued support for it.

Comment: Have a look at the plugin repository.  I know there's an Android plugin - not sure about iOS... https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Comment: Actually, here's the Android one I saw... https://github.com/Habel/TCPSockets